# Replace white space%20 white - in search url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I tried a lot of code without results.
I'm using wordpress and the url of search results is:

http://mysite.com/search/the%20search%20query%20

I need to change it in

http://mysite.com/search/the-search-query/

Is there a way with htaccess?

This is actually my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# END WordPress
```

The last rewrite rule is what i trie without success

Answer (score 2):

Your rule looks fine, however you have it **after** your routing rules. That means no matter what, that rule will never be reached because everything, including any request with a space in it, gets routed to `index.php`. You need to put any redirect rules **before** your routing rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\s|%20)(.+)$ /$1-$3 [R=301,QSA,L,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```